Short story where a Victorian gentleman travels to Mars, claims it for the British Empire and teaches the Martians English
In the early 70s, I read an SF anthology from the 60s or 70s.
One of the stories involved a Victorian gentleman (accidentally?) travelling to Mars. He finds it is inhabited and takes it upon himself to claim Mars for the British Empire and to teach the locals English, so he can communicate with them. (That is, the story is vaguely humourous.) A century later, a UN spaceship arrives to find Mars a British outpost and the Martians with British behaviours, to the dismay of an Irish member of the UN crew.

"Dominions Beyond" a.k.a. "The Second Trip to Mars", a short story by Ward Moore. You may have read it in one of these compilations, perhaps in the 1964 hardcover anthology The Saturday Evening Post Reader of Fantasy and Science Fiction, or a 1966 paperback edition of the same, or the 1974 paperback anthology Wondermakers 2 (Robert Hoskins, ed.), or The Magazine of Fantasy and Science Fiction, September 1973 (available at the Internet Archive).
The first trip to Mars:

Until its report was known, the Murphy-Gobiniev-Langois-Alemeda-Mutsuhara expedition to Mars in 2002 was thought to be the first successful one. Truth is, the first flight was achieved, quite accidentally, by a Humphrey Beachy-Cumberland in 1887, the year of Queen Victoria's Golden Jubilee.

The second trip (in 2002) gets a surprising reception:

"Desert," crowed Doctor Alemeda. "Sterile desert."
Langois shook his head obstinately, scanning the sands through field glasses. A dust cloud appeared, resolving into a crowd of people. "What did I tell you? Men! And, I hope, women also."
"Those bits of color seem to be flags," said Matsuhara.
"Impossible," said Murphy. "Some evolutionary quirk."
"Union Jacks," identified Alemeda.
"A plot!" cried Gobiniev. "A trick to discredit the U.S.S.R.!"

Murphy tries to claim Mars for the UN, but:

Prime Minister Aboxu stopped him with a wave of the hand. "I'm afraid you can't do that, you know."
"Well," said Murphy, "I can see that you're civilized; it's not like taking over an empty world. Perhaps you'll want to join the UN yourselves?"
"I'm afraid you don't understand," said the Prime Minister gently. "We're not a nation. At least not as you use the word. We owe our first and full allegiance to the Crown. After all, this is Her Majesty's Dominion of Mars and it is entirely up to Her Majesty—acting upon my advice—whether we join this—uh—United Nations thing."
"The fourth British Empire," muttered Sean Murphy brokenly. "Kathleen ni Houlihan, is there no justice?"


Iirc, when the Irish astronaut hears all this, he responds "The fourth British Empire. Kathleen Ni Houlihan, is there no justice?"

@MikeStone Good memory! I've edited that line into my answer.
